# Custom react hook - useState not working on initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and react hooks. I am creating a custom react hook. Why is useState not working as expected.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useMyHook = () => {
  const [myVal, setVal] = useState(0) //myVal is 0
  
  useEffect(() => {
    initialize()
  },[])
  
  const initialize = () => {
    setVal(100)
    console.log(myVal) // displays 0, not 100 as I expect
  }

  return myVal
}


// In my component I call it as follows
import { useMyHook } from 'useMyHook'
...
const myHook = useMyHook()
```

Comment: It's working how it's supposed to, the value is only updated on the next render. See [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the `useState` here.

First, when the component using the `useMyHook` is mounted, the `useEffect` runs as part of the initial render, and it calls the initialize function due to the `[]` dependency.

Then, inside the `initialize` function, you call `setVal(100)` to update the value of myVal. However, the update is asynchronous, meaning that the new value won't be available immediately. At this point, the `myVal` state variable still holds its old value of 0 because the state update is not yet completed

If you want to log the latest `myVal` value you can use `useEffect` like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    initialize()
  },[])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myVal) // Will display the updated value of myVal whenever it changes
  }, [myVal])

  const initialize = () => {
    setVal(100)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the updated value of myVal, you can use the useEffect hook with a dependency on myVal. When the value of myVal changes, the effect will run, and you can log the updated value.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useMyHook = () => {
  const [myVal, setVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    initialize();
  }, []);

  const initialize = () => {
    setVal(100);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myVal); // This will log the updated value of myVal whenever it changes
  }, [myVal]);

  return myVal;
};

import { useMyHook } from 'useMyHook';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const myHook = useMyHook();
};
```